# Getting BadMethodCallException when using JavaScript package

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I am sending a get request to a route and my controller picks up a collection from the database and then puts it into a javascript variable using Laracasts Javascript class (can be found [here](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer). It is a Php variable to javascript variable transformer- and I think it does so in a pretty standard way)

I do so like this:

```
$unReadNotifications = \App\Notification::join('users', 'notifications.notifier_user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('notifications.user_id', '=', $user->id)
    ->where('is_read', '=', 0)
    ->select('users.id as notifierId', 'users.username as username', 'notifications.id as id', 'notifications.subject as subject', 'notifications.body as body', 'notifications.notifiable_type as notifiable_type', 'notifications.notifiable_id as notifiable_id')
    ->orderBy('notifications.created_at', 'desc')
    ->with('notifiable')->get();

JavaScript::put(['unReadNotifications' => $unReadNotifications]);
```

and I am getting:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getTagNameListAttribute()
```

I did a `grep -r  getTagNameListAttribute *` and the only place it appears in my project is in a model (the model is actually related: some of my notifications belongTo a Notifiable which belongsTo a Content- this Content model is the one that has this method called getTagNameListAttribute and there is an appends array in that model which appends the output of that method to the model like so: `protected $appends = ['tag_name_list'];`).

The error is happening when running `JavaScript::put(['unReadNotifications' => $unReadNotifications]);` because when I put a `dd` right before this, all is fine, and anytime after I still get the error.

I am guessing that the Javascript::put is somehow calling some sort of get on a notification's notifiable's Content. This code works when all of the notifications are the kind that their notifiable have a Content, but now when the notification's notifiable does not have a content, I am getting this error. But I don't really understand why it would do that.

Any ideas as to what is going on?